# What's the best way to expose and compose errors in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling

I'm writing a module that talks to a REST API, and since the REST API provides nice, semantic error responses (e.g. 403 vs. 503), I want to convey those semantic errors to callers.

(Edit: what I mean by that is, the caller should be able to programmatically understand the cause of the error and act accordingly, e.g. display the appropriate UI.)

What's the best way for me to do so?

1. Create my own `Error` subclasses for those semantics, e.g. `mymodule.ForbiddenError`, `mymodule.ServiceUnavailableError`? Callers would then check `instanceof` to derive semantics. This is most typical in statically-typed languages like C# and Java.
2. Add e.g. a `mymoduleCode` property to standard `Error` instances, with semantic strings like `'Forbidden'` or `'ServiceUnavailable'`. Node.js itself does this, e.g. `code: 'ECONNREFUSED'`.
3. Some other way?

==

I'm writing another module now, that wraps the first module. I don't want to expose the internal module's errors directly, but it'd be nice to compose/wrap them, for debuggability.

What's again the best way for me to do so?

1. Add e.g. an `internalError` property to my `Error` instances that references the internal module's `Error` instance. Again C# and Java do this. ([Exception#InnerException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.innerexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) / [Throwable#cause](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#getCause%28%29))
2. Some other way?

Most tooling I've seen, though, only displays the `stack` property of `Error` instances, so this data would get lost in those cases. Is there a typical/conventional way that already exists?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found this great article that talks about this:

http://www.joyent.com/developers/node/design/errors

Too much to paste here, but under "Specific recommendations", items 2 through 5 address this:

> 1. Be clear about what your function does.
> 2. **Use `Error` objects (or subclasses) for all errors, and implement the `Error` contract.**
> 3. **Use the Error's `name` property to distinguish errors programmatically.**
> 4. **Augment the `Error` object with properties that explain details**
> 5. **If you pass a lower-level error to your caller, consider wrapping it instead.**

And in particular, the article links to this module for wrapping/composing errors:

https://github.com/joyent/node-verror

I'm not sure I'll necessary follow these *exact* conventions — e.g. I see value in having an application-domain `code` property — but the principles are very helpful.

Comment: node-verror is great but has one problem that is fatal IMO - It crashes when trying to print null / undefined string. You can try this fork which fixes this issue: https://github.com/naddison36/node-verror

Comment: does anyone know what is meant here by "impelement the Error contract" in #2?

Comment: I assume it's referring to setting `name`, `message`, and `stack` (via `Error.captureStackTrace`).

Answer (score 6):

The use case you describe is one that is definitely underserved by Node right now. Inasmuch as there are conventions in use, they tend to be some mixture of:

1. Creating new error types that simply derive from the Error constructor. Useful mostly for creating high-level categories of errors. You *can* use `instanceof` to discriminiate between types of errors, but that doesn't feel very JavaScripty.
2. Creating Java-style Error subtypes that take another error as a constructor argument and then wrap them. If you make the subtype expose an API, you're basically using polymorphism instead of direct dispatch to handle the errors based on types.
3. Creating semantically useful error messages via the Error constructor. This is a pattern I tend to use a lot.
4. Attaching properties to Errors, which is also extremely common.
5. Create a decoupled error-handling API that can be invoked from wherever the error originates. This gives you a single place to concentrate all the code that figures out what kind of error you have and what you should do with it, and inject whatever dependencies you need to handle the errors.

The real problem here is that these are all ad hoc mechanisms and I wouldn't say that any of them have reached critical mass. I think this is in part due to the fact that the combination of asynchronicity and JavaScript makes it tough to correctly and completely handle errors, so the recommendation is generally to shut down the whole process after capturing information about the error.

This doesn't do a great job of dealing with expected errors, but I think most of those errors are either captured by the framework (e.g. Express error handlers) or put into the Node callback convention. In short, I think there's room here to define some conventions, because the state of the art isn't that artful.

Comment: Thanks for the nice summary.  Can I propose adding the 'aseemSays' property as the standard?  :-)

Comment: Thanks Forrest, agreed nice summary. You're right that most times errors aren't / don't need to be semantically analyzed, but I've run into several cases where I do. E.g. I call a function to register a new user, and it throws an error. Is that bc the db is down? Or bc a "unique email" constraint failed? I want to act differently in those two cases. Sounds like attaching properties is what you'd do there?

Answer (score 1):

**Edit** I'm new to StackOverflow *and* Node.js. Someone else should answer this question! :-)

If you're coming from Java/C# welcome to JavaScript! I've never seen a Node.js library use `instanceof` to check for error types but as you've stated is pretty common in static  languages.

With that said, it's typical to just create new errors, and callback with those using NodeJS's style of callbacks `(err, response)`.

I run into error messages from other modules all the time, and it's helpful to know where they came from vs. creating wrapped error messages that may hide where it actually died on me (requiring more on my part to dig around).

An example of creating a function that could handle rest error messages that are strings (or in your case, invalid response):

```js
function myFunction(callback) {
    callRestAPI('http://someApi.com/request', function(errorString, jsonResponse) {
        if (errorString) { 
            callback(new Error("something wrong in myFunction! " + errorString)); 
        } else {
            callback(null, JSON.parse(jsonResponse));
        }
    });
}
```

In your case the "errorString" check would basically be the response (403 / 503) and you can structure your error message to be sent into `new Error( ... )`, e.g. `new Error('Failed! Got response 403!')`

I may have missed your point, maybe someone else can be more thorough.

---

After a re-read, can you post what module you are wrapping. Is it node-request?

Comment: Hey Glareo, thanks for the reply! I'm not new to Node, but I appreciate the welcome. =) I could have been clearer in my question: when I said "semantic", I meant exposing the fact that e.g. it's a client permissions error vs. a server overload error; so it shouldn't be in the string message. Node core adds a `code` property to its errors; this lets callers distinguish between error causes/types. But that doesn't lend itself to composability too nicely. Does that make sense?

Comment: I was asking this question generically, but one concrete case I'm looking to apply it to is this db driver module I maintain: http://npmjs.org/package/neo4j And I'm wrapping that in a business-logic module I'm writing for an app. Currently, this db module just throws non-semantic standard `Error` instances w/ string messages; I'd like to change that.

Comment: I'm probably the worst person to answer this then. I'm pretty new to Node.JS. Good luck :D

Comment: No problem. =) Thanks for taking the time to help, though!

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty new to node as well, so take this with a grain of salt, but I'd go with your #2 option, adding a property.  [(This is also suggested here)](http://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/errors/what-is-the-error-object).

This is pretty much your original #2 option.  If the error handlers just log the stack, not the error itself, that's their fault.  :-)    (seriously, not sure how you can do any better)

Comment: Thanks for the link! How do you think you'd compose errors then? Just extend the original instance with your own propert(y/ies)?

Comment: Yes.  I'd add a single property, named something like 'semanticDetails' or 'aseemSays'.  :-)  It could be a String, or it could be a { } itself with multiple properties: '.moduleName', '.errorCode' etc...  Document it so programmers receiving your errors know where to look.

Answer (score 0):

I'll simply attach an `httpCode` property to the error object. [KISS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle)

Comment: That might sound reasonable in my example, but assume in this case that the REST API is an implementation detail. E.g. if you're using a module to talk to service X, you're not expected to know the details of X's REST API, e.g. its various status codes.